# Is there a free code to html syntax highlighter written in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax-highlighting

Is there a free code to html syntax highlighter written in C#? I am looking for something I can host in an .net mvc app

Comment: ASP.NET MVC application front end is mostly HTML, javascript and css so you are probably looking for a C# syntax highlighter written in javascript. There are many of them around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**New answer**

These days I just use [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/) which works perfectly well with C#.

**Old answer**

While I haven't open-sourced it yet, you'd be welcome to the formatter I use for the C# in Depth web site. Give it a try, and let me know if you'd like to use it. *(This is no longer available.)*

Comment: @Jon are you still planning to release the source?

Comment: @Chris S: At some point, if I ever get time. I have too many other projects on at the moment though.

Comment: Yeah, I like it and I want to use the code for a project I am doing. Can we have the code?

Comment: The link to the CodeFormatterTool no longer works. Does it have a new home?

Comment: @SergeyVlasov: Unfortunately not - I didn't keep it up to date with new features etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access a command line tool, you can get pygments (it is python), but just pipe the output back into your app.

http://pygments.org/

It's has a multitude of output formats.

Comment: Not available at the time of your answer, but someone implemented pygments in C#: https://github.com/akatakritos/PygmentSharp

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a C# syntax highlighter using regex and a mini "state machine" (a few if statements)  [here](http://www.anotherchris.net/csharp/syntax-highlighter-for-csharp/), it could be adapted for C, C++ and Java fairly easily. It produces the inline styles by default and a pre tag.

The source is there in C#.

<sub>(Cross pollination answer)</sub>

Comment: Link is flagged due to a nefarious tracker.

Answer (score 0):

[ColorCode-Universal](https://github.com/WilliamABradley/ColorCode-Universal), which used to power syntax highlighting in Codeplex, works pretty well.