# highlight_string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, syntax-highlighting

Is there an equivalent of PHP's [highlight_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) function in C#?

It is not necessary to be a built-in function.

Edit: If not is there a good library for that?

**Edit2: I really need a server side solution for that like PHP does.**

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710653/is-there-a-free-code-to-html-syntax-highlighter-written-in-c

Comment: @Jimmy: Very true, this is a duplicate but I had read that one. The accepted answer does not provide a library (as far as i can see), the other one required javascript and last one is a command line tool. So there is no solution for my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in the framework that will give you the coloured output. You will have to use a library to do this.

[C# Code Format](http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/.) was one of the first .Net ones to come up in Google, although it only supports highlighting of C#, VB, HTML, XML, T-SQL or Monad. **It is capable of running server side though as it is written in C#.** If you need it to format PHP, then it is probably quite simple to extend it to do so - just make a custom PHPFormat class.

Comment: I've used C# Code Format as well, however I wasn't quite pleased with it. If I recall correctly it doesn't highlight as much as e.g. Visual Studio (or Google Code Prettify)
I don't say this because I'm stubborn, I just thought it might be useful to know.

That being said it's probably your best bet, if you want to run it server side.

Answer (score 2):

You can build yourself a basic syntax highlighter easy using RegExp.

Here's an example:

[Syntax Highlight in C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic57072.htm)

Or if you want a html C# highlighter written in C#

[C# Syntax Highlighter 2.0](http://www.nikhedonia.com/notebook/entry/c-syntax-highlighter-20/)

Or a JS highlighter:

[highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/)

Comment: @Pop Catalin: I will do it if i cannot find one :) Hope I can find it. I am lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, certainly not in the Framework itself. You'd have to look for libraries that support this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it for webpages (which I assume, since the PHP highlight function formats it as HTML) you can use Googles Code prettify. It's however a javascript, which on the other hand makes it code-behind language independent.

I'm using it at my site with great success :-)

You can find it here: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a SQL formatting library ([Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter](http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx) library) in C# (.Net 2.0) which, among the available options, supports just coloring the output (with html `span` tags).

It's available online for testing at http://poorsql.com, and here's a link that already sets the options to "just colorize" so you can test/play:

http://poorsql.com/?reFormat=false