# Showing text in textbox with actual formatting

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a website on the basis of asp demo for my students.In my website student can see chapterwise demo.
Now I am giving two button on every page,after clicking first one they can see source code of .aspx page and second one will show .cs code to them.
What I have done till now as student click on any of button,i read the content of file and showing.code in multiline textbox.
   these things are working properly,but my requirement that code should be displayed in same format as it in visual studio,like keywords should be display in blue font,same as it in vs.
Please any one help me....

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a lot harder than it sounds. Rather than trying to implement your own, I'd suggest taking a look at the suggestions given in this Stack Overflow post: [Is there a free code to html syntax highlighter written in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710653/is-there-a-free-code-to-html-syntax-highlighter-written-in-c) or looking at [this blog post](http://www.matlus.com/c-to-html-syntax-highlighter-using-roslyn/) which explains how to make a C# syntax highlighter using Roslyn.

Answer (score 0):

I have got it,downloaded colorcode dll that convert source code to formatted html.